# How can I limit anonymous users to viewing 3 nodes of a content type before signing up?

Tags: users

I have a content type that has a video link field (video is hosted off-site) and when you click the link it brings you to the video page full screen.  Are there any modules that will enable the ability to have an anonymous user only view a certain number of nodes of a given content type?

If not, what would be the best way to go about creating a module to do this?  Or is the scope of this module too heavy handed and I should look to limit the content type all together?

Comment: It will be pretty hard to determine which anonymous user is which, as they are anonymous. If you want viewing more nodes unpleasant, it may be doable. If you want to make viewing more nodes impossible - then forget it.

Comment: @Mołot Anonymous users can get their own sessions.  It's possible, but it complicates caching.

Comment: @MPD and they can clear & regenerate their own sessions at will, getting a brand new one with 0 on the counter, by clearing cookies. Many of them can even change IP at will. Or apparent country they are in. So making it irritating for them is easy, all right. Making it impossible for them? Can't do.

Comment: Please refer to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/190214/how-to-restrict-content-for-anonymous-users-after-they-viewed-more-than-two-arti